# Trigger function when div with class comes into view - but don't apply to all divs with that class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have spent hours and hours trying to get an animation working when a div with a specific class nears the top of the viewing window. I have something that works, but it's triggering all animations in divs with the class instead of just the one that's in view. I thought .each would prevent this from happening?

```
$(function() {
    var animated = $('.js-animate'),
        distance = $(animated).offset().top,
        $window = $(window);
    replaceWithPaths(animated);
    hideSVGPaths(animated);

    $window.scroll(function() {

        $(animated).each(function(i) {

            if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance-100 ) {
                startSVGAnimation(this);
                animated.splice(i,1);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I have tried using plugins (inview, waypoints), neither of which fit the bill. Is there a simple solution? As you may have gathered I'm just getting to grips with JS / Jquery, so if you answer please bear that in mind.

Comment: why are you comparing two constant values in $.each - distance and $window.scrollTop(). Value of distance will be same for all elements in variable **animated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this row:

```
distance = $(animated).offset().top
```

As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) says, `offset()` returns the offset of the first matched element, and not all of them.

Use this code instead:

```
$(function() {

    var animated = $('.js-animate'),
        distance = $(animated).offset().top,
        $window = $(window);

    replaceWithPaths(animated);
    hideSVGPaths(animated);

    $window.scroll(function() {

        $(animated).each(function(i) {

            //$(this).offset().top gives you the current offset of the current element.
            if ( $window.scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - 100 ) {
                startSVGAnimation(this);
                animated.splice(i,1);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Or, if you really want to save the offsets so you don't have to access the property over and over again when scrolling, you can save them like this:

```
//Saves the distances to an array.
distance = animated.map(function() {
    return $(this).offset().top;
}).get()
```

And them access them inside the `each` function like this:

```
if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance[i] - 100 ) {
    //...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. I guess saving to an array provides better performance?

Comment: Yes, it should, but I have no idea if it's enough to be of any importance or not. Shouldn't hurt, though.